# Oracle SQ Identify Siblings via siblings

Tags: sql, oracle, recursion, hierarchy

I have linked together groups of records which are related via a shared parent.  Unfortunately there are some quite complicated family groups, and it's become clear that just using a shared parental relationship isn't enough - I also want to take into account sibling relationships.

To be clear - this is actual family groups, which are currently identified if their is a shared mother or father relationship, but in some cases a child may not share parents with another child who is still linked to them via a sibling.

[image]

So in the above example, Lou has no shared parental relationship with Stacey, but Stacey is the sister of Nate who is the brother of Deb who is the sister of Lou, which links them together.

For arguments sake let's say we have some SQL like this:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.SIBS FROM A
```

Which produces a dataset like this:

```
ID  SIBS
A   B
A   C
B   A
C   A
C   D
D   C
```

I would like to produce a table from the above dataset which takes into account siblings of siblings - for example sibling C is related to sibling D and Sibling A, but is related to sibling B via sibling A.  The resulting table would look like this:

```
ID  SIBS
A   B
A   C
A   D
B   C
B   D
B   A
C   A
C   D
C   B
D   C
D   A
D   B
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Please insert your examples as formatted text.

Comment: You are misusing the word sibling. Siblings are transitive: if A is a sibling of B, and B is a sibling of C then A is a sibling of C. Find another word that better describes the relationship.

Comment: @Tony94 - sorry, I always have trouble with this.  I tried to paste from excel into the post and it did it automatically as a picture.

Comment: @RedFilter - actually, this is talking about literal familial siblings but I see your point.  I'm not sure how else to describe them - some share a parent, others just share a sibling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its unclear whether the relationships are reflexive (i.e. if `B` is a "sibling" of `A` then `A` is a "sibling" of `B`) as you have some duplicate rows with the reversed relationships in your data and some where this property is not evident.

Assuming that your relationships are not reflexive then:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/45671/2)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE A ( ID, SIBS ) AS
SELECT 'A', 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A', 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B', 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'C', 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'D', 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'E', 'F' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'F', 'G' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'G', 'H' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT( ID ) AS ID,
       SIBS
FROM   A
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ROOT( ID ) <> SIBS
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       PRIOR SIBS = ID
ORDER BY ID, SIBS
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/45671/2/0)**:

```
| ID | SIBS |
|----|------|
|  A |    B |
|  A |    C |
|  A |    D |
|  B |    A |
|  B |    C |
|  B |    D |
|  C |    A |
|  C |    B |
|  C |    D |
|  D |    A |
|  D |    B |
|  D |    C |
|  E |    F |
|  E |    G |
|  E |    H |
|  F |    G |
|  F |    H |
|  G |    H |
```

**Query 2**: If they are reflexive then you can use `UNION [ALL]` to duplicate the table with the relationships in the reverse direction and then use the previous technique:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT( ID ) AS ID,
       SIBS
FROM   (
  SELECT ID, SIBS FROM A
  UNION
  SELECT SIBS, ID FROM A
)
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ROOT( ID ) <> SIBS
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       PRIOR SIBS = ID
ORDER BY ID, SIBS
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/45671/2/1)**:

```
| ID | SIBS |
|----|------|
|  A |    B |
|  A |    C |
|  A |    D |
|  B |    A |
|  B |    C |
|  B |    D |
|  C |    A |
|  C |    B |
|  C |    D |
|  D |    A |
|  D |    B |
|  D |    C |
|  E |    F |
|  E |    G |
|  E |    H |
|  F |    E |
|  F |    G |
|  F |    H |
|  G |    E |
|  G |    F |
|  G |    H |
|  H |    E |
|  H |    F |
|  H |    G |
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, you were right in your assumption that they are not reflexive, the data is based on actual family groups where there is at least one shared parent, but in some cases you may have children who do not share a parent but they do share a sibling!  Solution A works.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to a hierarchical query, you coudl also use [recursive subquery factoring](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__BCEJGIBG):

```
with r (pno, sibs) as (
  select a.id, a.sibs
  from a
  union all
  select r.pno, a.sibs
  from r
  join a on a.id = r.sibs
)
cycle pno, sibs set is_cycle to 1 default 0
select distinct pno, sibs
from r
where pno != sibs
order by pno, sibs;

PNO SIBS
--- ----
A   B   
A   C   
A   D   
B   A   
B   C   
B   D   
C   A   
C   B   
C   D   
D   A   
D   B   
D   C
```

The anchor member gets the raw data from your table. The recursive member joins each row found so far back to your main table, keeping the original `pno` (as the equivalent to `connect_by_root(id)`).

The hierarchical query is likely to perform better, I think, but it depends a bit on your data, so you could try both approaches.

Comment: Thank you for this, as you stated the answer provided by @MT0 worked quicker, so I've marked that as the answer, however it was helpful to have an alternative (again, I know it difficult when you don't get to see the dataset).