# Oracle SQ Identify Siblings via siblings and calculate related ratio

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, graph-algorithm

I have a linked group of related records and their associated ratio. Unfortunately not all of the ratios are captured but rather they can be derived from other ratios. As in I may require a ratio of A -> D and I do not however have a direct ratio to refer to but I can derive it from the example below by taking the ratio of A->C (0.5) and then C->D (3) therefore 0.5 * 3 = 1.5. OR I could derive B by inverting the ratio of A->B (1/2 = 0.5) and then take the ratio of A->C (0.5) therefor (1/2) * 0.5 = 0.25 and so on and so forth.

For example

```
FROM_UNIT_ID  TO_UNIT_ID  RATIO
A             B           2
A             C           0.5
C             D           3
```

What I want to do is calculate an entire list of all possible paths and their ratios as demonstrated below.

```
FROM_UNIT_ID  TO_UNIT_ID  RATIO
A             B           2
A             C           0.5
C             D           3
A             D           1.5
B             C           0.25
B             D           0.75
B             A           0.5
C             A           2
C             B           4
D             A           0.666666667
D             B           1.333333333
D             C           0.333333333
```

Using the following [stack overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53616010/oracle-sq-identify-siblings-via-siblings) I have been able to derive all of the siblings of a ration to get a list of the possible paths but I have been unable to adapt this query to calculate the ratios. I am using Oracle 11g.

```
SELECT
       CONNECT_BY_ROOT( FROM_UNIT_ID ) AS FROM_UNIT_ID,
       TO_UNIT_ID
FROM   (
  SELECT FROM_UNIT_ID, TO_UNIT_ID, RATIO FROM RATIOS 
  UNION
  SELECT TO_UNIT_ID, UNIT_ID, 1/RATIO AS RATIO FROM RATIOS 
)
WHERE  CONNECT_BY_ROOT( FROM_UNIT_ID ) <> TO_UNIT_ID
CONNECT BY NOCYCLE
       PRIOR TO_UNIT_ID = FROM_UNIT_ID
ORDER BY FROM_UNIT_ID, TO_UNIT_ID;
```

Comment: For your simple example there are no conflicts.  But if your table had `B C 10`, what would the answer be?

Comment: Is your Oracle version 11g or just 11gR2? The latter has CTEs.

Comment: As @TheImpaler said - this is one case where we must know the detailed Oracle version you have. 11 is fine, but 11.1 and 11.2 are still very different. What do you see when you `select banner from v$version`?

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Release 11.2.0.4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle 11.2 and higher (where recursive `WITH` clause is available), you could do it like this (assuming that the data in the input table doesn't contradict itself):

```
with
  test_data (from_unit_id, to_unit_id, ratio) as (
    select 'A', 'B', 2   from dual union all
    select 'A', 'C', 0.5 from dual union all
    select 'C', 'D', 3   from dual
  )
, symm_data (x, y, r) as (
    select case when h.source = 1 then from_unit_id else to_unit_id   end,
           case when h.source = 1 then to_unit_id   else from_unit_id end,
           case when h.source = 1 then ratio        else 1/ratio      end
    from   test_data cross join 
                     (select 1 as source from dual union all select 2 from dual) h
  )
, all_nodes (x) as (
    select distinct x
    from   symm_data
  )
, rec (x, y, r) as (
    select x, x, 1
      from all_nodes
    union all
    select r.x, s.y, r.r * s.r
      from rec r join symm_data s on r.y = s.x
  )
  cycle x, y set cycle to 'Y' default 'N'
select x as from_unit_id, y as to_unit_id, round(r, 4) as ratio 
from   rec
where  cycle = 'N' and x != y
order  by x, y
;
```

Output:

```
FROM_UNIT_ID TO_UNIT_ID        RATIO
------------ ------------ ----------
A            B                     2
A            C                    .5
A            D                   1.5
B            A                    .5
B            C                   .25
B            D                   .75
C            A                     2
C            B                     4
C            D                     3
D            A                 .6667
D            B                1.3333
D            C                 .3333
```

Note - I used `ROUND` in the final `SELECT`; normally that should only be used in the final report, otherwise you shouldn't round numbers anywhere.

Comment: I managed to get this to calculate it perfectly. I did have to use `alter session set cursor_sharing = EXACT;` to get around a bug I believe in binding the variables in a cycle on my version of Oracle. Would you use this approach if the ratios weren't fixed but rather changed day by day?

Comment: @garyamorris - I don’t see the difference between the ratios being fixed and them changing day by day. What does that even mean? In any case, yes, I would use the same approach, whatever you mean by “ratios changing day by day”.

Comment: As in ratio changing day by day like exchange rates, I tried that approach anyway and as you say it does work. One last question why do you use the cross join in symm_data rather than a union?

Comment: @garyamorris - A `UNION ALL` is indeed the natural choice (easier to understand). The `CROSS JOIN` thing is a trick of the trade, based on understanding how things are actually done. For a `UNION ALL`, the base data must be read twice - and "reading the data" is time consuming. With the cross join trick, the same data only needs to be read once; one row of input produces two rows of output in a single pass. It is **only** for speed of processing and no other reason; but it does help a lot for massive inputs.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by calculating the values for all the individual unit_ids assuming one of them to be 1, then use that to calculate the ratio:

```
--Creating the sample table

Create table ratios as
(select 'A' as FROM_UNIT_ID,'B' as  TO_UNIT_ID,cast(2 as float) as  RATIO from dual union
select 'A','C',0.5 from dual union
select 'C', 'D',3 from dual);

--Creating a list of unique unit_ids

Create table unit_id as
select a.*,CAST(NULL as float) as Val from
(select distinct from_unit_id as unit_id from ratios
UNION
select distinct to_unit_id as unit_id from ratios)a;

--Updating the first value to be 1

UPDATE unit_id
SET Val=1
WHERE rownum=1;

--Updating the other values based on the known values

UPDATE unit_id
SET Val=
(select Calc from 
(Select a.Unit_ID,c.Val*b.ratio as Calc
FROM unit_id a
INNER JOIN ratios b on a.unit_id=b.to_unit_id
INNER JOIN unit_id c on c.unit_id=b.from_unit_id) b 
WHERE Unit_ID.Unit_Id=b.Unit_Id)
WHERE Unit_ID.Val is null;

--Updating the other values based on the known values
--You can repeat this step a couple more times if needed

UPDATE unit_id
SET Val=
(select Calc from 
(Select a.Unit_ID,c.Val*b.ratio as Calc
FROM unit_id a
INNER JOIN ratios b on a.unit_id=b.to_unit_id
INNER JOIN unit_id c on c.unit_id=b.from_unit_id) b 
WHERE Unit_ID.Unit_Id=b.Unit_Id)
WHERE Unit_ID.Val is null;

select a.Unit_id as from_unit_id,
      b.unit_id as to_unit_id,
      trunc(a.val/b.val,2) as ratio
from unit_id a
cross join unit_id b
where a.unit_id<>b.unit_id
order by a.unit_id,b.unit_id
```

Hope this helps.